# Loading assembly error Azure Graph Client

Tags: wpf, winforms, azure

I have an application that uses plugins. One of the plugins which I newly created is a plugin which makes connection to Azure Graph Client.

The plugins are loading with a Windows Forms application. This works just fine. I created a new application in WPF, but now the plugins throws an error

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient,
>   Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When I look into my plugins folder I see the assemblies but with other version numbers.

How can I fix this problem. I find it very strange because the WFA works like a charm but the WPF generates an error. Application has full rights and is probing in the correct folder. I can load the plugin, but when trying the assembly.GetTypes() I got the error.

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 all updates installed and added the Graph assembly through NuGET packages. I'm using C# for my project.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Because I have been using Xamarin. And Use to get this because the package wasnt added assembly

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015. No special things and C#